# AOSP: How can I write some file in system service

Tags: android, android-source, android-permissions

I want to write a file to record time logs in my new system service.

So, I made a new system service and added to SystemServer.java (ServiceManager.addService).

It just creates a new file into the external storage.

But, It doesn't work.

**java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

this is a log.

how can i solve this problem? please help me.

Comment: Can you at least post your code and stack trace?

Comment: i added some explanation. please check this and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your manifest?

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: thank you. but it is not application level's problem. it is android framework source.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. The system server process also needs permission to write files. Not in the "use-permission" way. You should add necessary groups in the `--setgroups` option when starting `SystemServer` in the `ZygoteInit`.